# Costco CST80SL fan wiring

Tags: electrical, wiring, bathroom, exhaust-fan

I want to replace my old bathroom fan with a CST80SL BROAN bathroom fan.  Originally, there are two switches in my bathroom, one for bathroom fan and the other for bathroom light.  My question is can I use one switch to control unit light, my existing bathroom light and the fan (BLK wire from unit light, BLK wire from existing light and BLK wire from fan tie together), and the other switch for built-in humidity control unit (BRN wire)?  (and Grey wire will be unused).

Answer (score 1):

### This will work

This will work fine -- there's no issue with having an exhaust fan on the same circuit as other lights.  Just don't put it over a shower or tub, because then it'll need to be on a GFCI, and having bathroom lighting on a GFCI isn't a very good idea.